# Undefined variable on empty database row

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting this annoying error when my database row is empty, 
But the rows are supposed to be empty until i add some values to it.
Any clues whats going wrong ? I tried to disable the problem by adding @ before the variables but that doesn't work when they are in a foreach loop.

If I add data to the rows, the problems stops....

any ideas ?

some code.

```
$tweets = new Tweets();     
    foreach($tweets->fetch_tweets($_GET['uid']) as $tweet){
    @$tweet_name = $tweet['username'];
    @$tweet_date= $tweet['date'];
    @$tweet_email= $tweet['email'];

    }
function fetch_tweets($uid){ /*Mine and users   I follow*/

$uid = (int)$uid;
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT user.id,
  user.email, 
    user.username, 
  tweets.message, 
    tweets.date, 
  userdetails.profile_img, 
    userdetails.firstname, 
  userdetails.lastname, 
    following.id, following.user_id, 
  following.follow_id
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN following ON user.id = following.user_id 
    JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
    JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
    WHERE user.id='{$uid}'  OR 
                user.id IN (SELECT follow_id 
                            FROM following 
                            WHERE following.user_id = '{$uid}' )  GROUP BY tweets.date ORDER BY tweets.date DESC "
);
$tweet = array();
while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !==FALSE) { 
$tweet[] = $row;
} echo $query->rowCount();
return $tweet; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the returned array is empty before you try to use it.

```
$tweets = new Tweets();
$res = $tweets->fetch_tweets($_GET['uid']);
if( empty($res) ) {
    echo "no tweets.";
} else {
    foreach($res as $tweet){
        $tweet_name = $tweet['username'];
        $tweet_date = $tweet['date'];
        $tweet_email= $tweet['email'];
    }
}
```

Also, you should always declare your functions *before* calling them. It's not a requirement in PHP as it is in most other languages, but it makes your code much easier to read.

Comment: Ic, actually i though this would work. its giving me the echo " no tweets, but the error message is still there,
could it be because im calling it with an echo from another page ?
like this.
<?php echo $tweet_email.' @'.$tweet_name?> ?

Answer (score 0):

Just run a code to check if number of rows is 0 before fetching the rows